# Substitution of ${...} from SpringBoot Yaml config file in Swagger annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have inherited a SpringBoot micro-service project that uses a YAML config file (`application.yml` + several others, including the `application-swagger.yml`).

I want to enter meaningful documentation for the Swagger pages using mostly Swagger annotations, but still be able to enter lengthy text blocks from a Yaml file. So for instance I can put keys in the Yaml file for `@ApiOperation`:

```
swaggerdoc:
  service:
    operation:
      create: 
        notes: |
          Some markdown-enhanced text
```

and

```
@ApiOperation(notes="${swaggerdoc.service.operation.create.notes}",
         value="${swaggerdoc.service.operation.create.value}")
```

and the Yaml file content indeed shows up on the Swagger page.

But if I try to put a description in the same way on the class that describes the JSON payload:

```
@ApiModel(description="${swaggerdoc.service.dto.payload.description}") 
public class Payload {
...
}
```

the value is not substituted, and appears as is in the Swagger page:

```
description:  ${swaggerdoc.service.dto.payload.description}
```

Needless to say that I have checked names and proper indentation more than once. I can even copy the value that works in the `@ApiOperation` and it won't work in the `@ApiModel`.

Futhermore if under that very `@ApiModel` I use a

```
@ApiModelProperty(value="${swaggerdoc.service.dto.payload.attribute.value}")
```

Then that substitution works for the `@ApiModelProperty`!!!

Am I missing something? Or is it a know problem?

Using

- SpringBoot 2.2.7
- Swagger 1.5.20
- SpringFox 2.9.2

Comment: The `{}` feature is only available for annotations that are processed by Spring (specifically SpEL) somewhere. I am not aware that the Swagger annotations are.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works for the others...